# prime numbers - need a help

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, binomial-coefficients

Helow,

There is a question about prime numbers.

> Let $\pi(m, n)$ denote the set of prime numbers in the interval $[m, n]$.
> 1. Show that $\prod_{p \in \pi(m+1,2 m)} p \leq\left(\begin{array}{c}2 m \\ m\end{array}\right)$
> .2. Use the previous item to show that $\prod_{p \in \pi(1, n)} p \leq 4^{n}$.
> 3. Deduce from the previous item that $|\pi(1, n)|=O(n / \log n)$.

Supposed that I already answer the first section.

I try to answer the second section, but if n $\neq$ $2^{k}$ (for some k from the natural numbers, for this case I succeed) I dont know how the prove better Upper bound other then $4^{2n}$. (I get to this base on the fact that for any k, the inequality   $2^k \choose 2^{k-1}$ $\leq$ $4^{2^{k-1}}$ exists).

I also tried to prove the third section based on the first and the second sections but I honesty have no idea how...

I will be glad to get any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Since the second part is based on the first part, would you at least be able to provide your solution for part one so we know what kind of approach you are expecting?